# Find even function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)+f(x-2) = x^2-2x+1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: functional-equations

> Find $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)+f(x-2) = x^2-2x+1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, given that $f$ is is an even function.

I have tried putting $$x = x+2$$ and also $$x=-x$$but that gives the same thing, I don't know I am unable to make any progress. I also tried differentiating the function, because we were taught sometimes it could be solved like that, and I also know differentiation of an even function is an odd function, but it's also not helping.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac {x^{2}-1} 2$ is a solution.

Comment: Yes, but how will we reach there .

Comment: @geetha290krm Even if you could give some hint, what should I do because the above process isn't helping.

Comment: I don't yet know how to find the general solution. I just looked for a polynomial solution and that was easy.

Comment: See this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3933069/399263, according to the answer (I didn't verified completely but that seems correct) $f(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{2}+g(x)$ where $g$ is any function of period $4$ at least for the class of function chosen there.

Comment: @zwim yeah that was useful as well. It was the same question just the way of writing the functional equation was different, yeah but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $p$ is a real polynomial that satisfies $p(x)+p(x-2)=x^2-2x+1$.
Note that the leading terms of $p(x)$ and $p(x-2)$ do not cancel out when they sum together.
Thus, $p$ must be a quadratic polynomial.
By letting $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$,
we can find that $p(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{2}$
as in the comments.

Now, suppose $f$ is an even function that satisfies
$$
f(x)+f(x-2)=x^2-2x+1. \tag{1}
$$
We can write $f=p+g$,
where $g$ is another function.
Substituting back into $(1)$, we have
$$
g(x)=-g(x-2) \tag{2}
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
Since $f$ and $p$ are even functions, $g$ is also even, so
$$
g(x)=g(-x) \tag{3}
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
Note that equations $(2)$ and $(3)$
are also sufficient conditions for $p+g$ being a solution.

Equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ show that $g$ is completely determined by its image on $[0,1)$,
and $g(x)=0$ for all $x\in 1+2\mathbb{Z}$.
This is not hard to show.
First, by equation $(2)$,
$g$ is completely determined by its image on $[0,2)$.
Now, for all $x\in (1,2)$,
we have $g(x)=-g(x-2)=-g(2-x)$.
Since $2-x\in (0,1)$ for all $x\in (1,2)$,
the image of $g$ on $(1,2)$ is determined by the image of $g$ on $(0,1)$.
Also, $g(1)=-g(2-1)=-g(1)$, so $g(1)=0$
and hence $g(x)=0$ for all $x\in 1+2\mathbb{Z}$ by equation $(2)$.

Since equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ are sufficient conditions
for $p+g$ being a solution,
any arbitrary function $h:[0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$
induces a solution as shown above.
In other words,

> An even function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies
> $f(x)+f(x-2)=x^2-2x+1$
> for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$
> if and only if
> there exists a function $h:[0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$
> such that $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2}+g(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, where
> $$g(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> h(x-\lfloor x \rfloor) & x\in (0,1)+4\mathbb{Z} \\
> -h(1-(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)) & x\in (1,2)+4\mathbb{Z} \\
> -h(x-\lfloor x \rfloor) & x\in (2,3)+4\mathbb{Z} \\
> h(1-(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)) & x\in (3,4)+4\mathbb{Z} \\
> h(0) & x\in 4\mathbb{Z} \\
> -h(0) & x\in 2+4\mathbb{Z} \\
> 0 & x\in 1+2\mathbb{Z}
> \end{cases}.
> $$

Comment: Why not just algebraically manipulate the given equation, or find various values to significantly narrow down the guesswork?

Comment: @DerekLuna Where is the guesswork? I did not "guess" the answer. The idea behind my approach is seeing that there is a unique polynomial solution, and by adding a function $g$ we can obtain all other solutions. Finding various values does not help in this case. Also, I did algebraically manipulate the given equation to obtain equation $(2)$.

Comment: Actually, since the answer is not unique, you cannot obtain a solution by solving linear equations in $f(x), f(x+2), f(x-2)$, which is likely what you meant by "algebraically manipulating the given equation".

Comment: I was just confused by the way the question was asked, and the "work" shown by the asker. It seemed that one must simply find a function, which could have been done much more easily as you know. I did not know if the asker meant to ask for the general solution.

Comment: @DerekLuna actually this was a question in my test, So I was only required to find the polynomial that he found out easily, but I was not aware that we could say directly it would be a polynomial which was quite obvious, but yeah that's the story.